# synchronous the databases at real time

Tags: mysql, synchronization, realtime

I have two databases, one in the domain and managed by phpMyAdmin, and the other is located on the local server. I want make the local one as master and the other reside in the domain as slave. With phpMyAdmin, can I synchronous the databases at real time ? How ?

NOTE: both databases are using MySQL.

In other words, Whenever I have add new table or data on the master database, I want to see the change on the slave also.

Other question; If possible, how can I do; If any change occurs on the specified table, namely foo_table, on the Domain database which is slave, I want to see this change on the local one which is master. All other masters, not including foo_table, tables are synchronized with the other tables on the slave database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL replication, although it is not synchronous, so there will be a delay (usually seconds).

There is more information on replication in MySQL documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html